# File produced by r.js powered Node build script doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd, r.js

### The source

My `src` has the following structure :

```
src
|-- index.html
|-- js
|    |-- amdconfig.js
|    |-- main.js
|    |-- ...
|-- lib
     |-- require
     |    |-- require.js
     |-- d3
     |    |-- d3.js
     |-- luciad
          |-- ...
```

My `index.html` contains the following code :

```
<script src="./lib/requirejs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- require.js -->
<script src="./js/amdconfig.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- require.js config -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["app/js/main"]); /* main module */
</script>
```

My `amdconfig.js` file contains the following code :

```
(function(configure, app) {
  var lib = [app, "lib"].join("/");
  configure({
    baseUrl : app,
    urlArgs : "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    packages : [{
      name : "requirejs",
      location : [lib, "requirejs"].join("/")
    }, {
      name : "luciad",
      location : [lib, "luciad"].join("/")
    }, {
      name : "d3",
      location : [lib, "d3"].join("/")
    }, {
      name : "app",
      location : app
    }],
    cache : {}
  })
})(
  require.config ? require.config /* RequireJS */ : require, /* Dojo */
  '.'
)
```

---

#### My build script

I have a build script with the following structure :

```
builder
|-- build.js
|-- package.json
```

If has the following code :

```
require('requirejs').optimize({
  baseUrl: '../src',
  paths: {
    main: 'main',
    requirejs : './lib/requirejs',
    luciad : './lib/luciad',
    d3 : './lib/d3',
    app : './'
  },
  name: 'js/main',
  out : '../dist/main.js',
  optimize: "uglify2",
  uglify2: {
    output: {
      beautify: false
    },
    compress: {},
    warnings: true,
    mangle: true
  }
}, function (buildResponse) {
  console.log(buildResponse);
});
```

---

#### My problem

The build script does produce a minified `main.js` file and outputs the list of included files in the console, as expected.

However, when I replace the `main.js` of my `src` with the `main.js` I just generated, nothing happens. My app doesn't start and I'm not getting any errors.

What am I missing here?

---

#### Note

If I don't minify my code, I get the same behavior.

The generated file consists of a whole bunch of modules in this format :

```
define('namespaced/path',["dependency1", "dependency2"], function(a,b){...});
```

I suppose that is the expected format...

Comment: You have `baseUrl: '../scr'` which I suspect should be `baseUrl: '../src`. Are you able to run the code without optimization? It is definitely possible to mess things up through optimization. Also, you should check the network tab in your debugger and see what RequireJS is trying to load. Is it loading what you expect? Is it generating 404s? (I know you said you're not getting any errors but what this means vary from person to person.)

Comment: Yes, it should be `src`. I just corrected that. And yes, I get the same issue when I don't minify my code. --- When I looked at the debugger, I noticed that my `main.js` was in fact loaded and my console was completely empty...

Comment: Please provide the code of your `main.js`. Maybe the uglifyer is broken. Could you try executing r.js with `optimize: 'none'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what caused my issue.

The produced output looked something this :

```
define('luciad/util/create',[],function(){...});
define('luciad/error/_createError',["../util/create"],function(a){...});
define('luciad/error/ProgrammingError',["./_createError"],function(a){...)});
...
define('js/main',[...],function(...){...});
```

Note the last line. There, my main module is called `js/main`. However, my main module is called in my HTML file like this :

```
require(["app/js/main"]);
```

So, what happened, was that `require(["app/js/main"])` failed silently because it couldn't find a module named `app/js/main`.

The solution was surprisingly simple. All I had to do, was rename the `name` parameter from `js/main` to `app/js/main`. Now, everything works as expected.

I don't know how I could have missed this, but I guess the silent fail of `require(["app/js/main"])` didn't exactly help.